# WSO2 Identity Server email authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We're using WSO2 identity server 5.0 with SP1.

We've followed [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Email+Authentication)  to enable e-mail authentication, which has worked.

But now we aren't able to edit the email address (both, backend and scim) with return code 500.

Have we missing some configurations which aren't mentioned in the documentation or something, we've ran out of ideas.

Our user-mgt.xml:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
    <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
    <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
    <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
    <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>                                   
    <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin,ou=system</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
    <Property name="passwordHashMethod">SHA</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=identityPerson)(mail=*))</Property>
    <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">identityPerson</Property>
    <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=identityPerson)(mail=?))</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameAttribute">mail</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="ServicePasswordJavaRegEx">^[\\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="ServiceNameJavaRegEx">^[\\S]{2,30}/[\\S]{2,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
    <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
    <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    <Property name="SharedGroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    <Property name="SharedGroupSearchBase">ou=SharedGroups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
    <Property name="SharedGroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
    <Property name="SharedGroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
    <Property name="SharedGroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
    <Property name="SharedTenantNameListFilter">(objectClass=organizationalUnit)</Property>
    <Property name="SharedTenantNameAttribute">ou</Property>
    <Property name="SharedTenantObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
    <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
    <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
    <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
</UserStoreManager>
```

SCIM Error:

> {"Errors":[{"description":"Error while updating attributes of user:
> customer@wso2.com","code":"500"}]}

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be there is some configuration missing in the doc, You need to add following property in to the user store configuration as well.  Other configuration seems to be fine.  Also you can find more and clear details  on enabling email username from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/07/email-username-with-identity-server/)

`<Property name="UsernameWithEmailJavaScriptRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9@._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>`

Also,  it is WSO2IS errors are logged in the`/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log` file.  It is better to check it for finding actual exception

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answer. We have added the missing property. our configuration seems to be the same as described in blog. In the /repository/logs/wso2carbon.log we found the following error.

```
Object : 'mail=customer@wso2.com,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org'
        Modification[0]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
mobile: (null)
        Modification[1]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
url: (null)
        Modification[2]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
givenName: John
        Modification[3]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
country: (null)
        Modification[4]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
sn: Doe
        Modification[5]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
telephoneNumber: (null)
        Modification[6]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
organizationName: (null)
        Modification[7]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
mail: customer2@wso2.com
        Modification[8]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
im: (null)
        Modification[9]
            Operation :  replace
            Modification
streetAddress: (null)
: ERR_62 Entry mail=customer@wso2.com,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org does not have the mail attributeType, which is part of the RDN";]; remaining name 'mail=customer@wso2.com'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3098)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3013)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2820)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:147)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:136)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doSetUserClaimValues(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:871)
    ... 121 more
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-06-04 10:48:39,046] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient} -  org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Profile information could not be updated in ApacheDS LDAP user store {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-06-04 11:11:29,749] ERROR {org.apache.directory.server.core.schema.SchemaInterceptor} -  ERR_62 Entry mail=customer@wso2.com,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org does not have the mail attributeType, which is part of the RDN"; {org.apache.directory.server.core.schema.SchemaInterceptor}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-06-04 11:11:29,749] ERROR {org.apache.directory.server.core.schema.SchemaInterceptor} -  ERR_62 Entry mail=customer@wso2.com,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org does not have the mail attributeType, which is part of the RDN"; {org.apache.directory.server.core.schema.SchemaInterceptor}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-06-04 11:11:29,750] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver} -  Profile information could not be updated in ApacheDS LDAP user store {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver}
org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.mgt.UserProfileException: Profile information could not be updated in ApacheDS LDAP user store
```

Comment: You can update the your question with logs. Do not need to add it as a new answer :)

Comment: According to the error,  you are sending the  email attribute of the user in SCIM request..  please do not send it..  as your username also contains it.  You can modify it again.

Comment: This error occurs in the WSO2 console and SCIM. But how can we update or modify the user email address without sending the new values?

Comment: Email is in your DN and it is not allowed to update by WSO2IS, Normally WSO2IS does not allow to update the username..  there are some reference to username.  If it is changed there can be issue..  So best way to configure some other attribute for username and you can use email for attribute for login.  It is already mentioned in the link i posted..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Is there any guide, how to change the default attribute for the username?